# CodeIgniter: Pagination displaying links but not showing certain results per page

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, pagination

Hi this is a probably really obvious but I am new to pagination and I think the documentation for CI is REALLY rubbish, what I expect to get is a link list and when I click on each one it should display 3 of my li items per page, it is showing the link list and the links work, but it isn't showing a certain amount of results per page, can anybody help me with this?

My Controller section:

```
public function clist()
    {
        //load the model that gets a list of clients
        $this->load->model('list_model'); 
        //call the function that lists clients and store the return data in a variable
        $fields = $this->list_model->listcliname(); 
        //create an array
        $data = array();
        //assign the data to a key in the array
        $data['fields'] = $fields;
        //pass the array to view for handling and load the view.

        $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = site_url('clientlist/clist');
    $config['total_rows'] = 500;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('clientlist', $data);
```

My View:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> client list </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/clientlist.css">
<!--  add script to add jquery and add a function that performs a confirm on the event of a click on the delete link. --> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.confirmation').on('click', function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <?php
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                 ?>
                 <ul>
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['name']; ?>
                 </li> 
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['contact']; ?>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                <form action="clistedit" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="UID" value="<?php echo $field['UID']?>">
                <button type="submit">edit</button>
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/clientlist/delete/<?php echo $field['UID']; ?>/" class="confirmation">delete</a>
                <a href="/clientlist/salelead/<?php echo $field['UID']; ?>/">view lead</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                 <?php
            }

            ?>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Do I have to configure somewhere what data is being paginated or does the link to the function do that?

Comment: how does echo '<pre>'; print_r( $fields ); echo '</pre>'; looks like ?

Comment: It prints out every array I have on page 1

Comment: and 2 etc, it's like the links link to exactly the same thing, just not limited.

Comment: Also, i recommend moving from Codeigniter to [laravel](http://laravel.com), if you can. Easy to learn and loaddsss of libraries to make your life easier.

Comment: @seanyt123 i know what it does, i would like to know how it looks :)

Comment: Exactly how you would expect it to, it shows all the data in the array and it shows each array without limit. I can't give you any more information than that, this is a client database, I can't go giving you the information stored in these arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which segment of your uri will contain your `page_number`, aka the `uri_segment` config of pagination.

Normally, the page number will be found at the end of your uri `clientlist/clist`

Your Controller code will then be:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('clientlist/clist');
$config['total_rows'] = 500;
$config['per_page'] = 3;
//Appends the page number to the url
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And in your view, you will have to echo the `$pagination` to receive the pagination links.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer isn't really helpful, the uri_segment isn't necessary config, it has a default and also my problem isn't with seeing the pagination links, I can see them fine because I can use echo $this->pagination->create_links(); in my controller like I did to see them, the problem is the results aren't limited, each page displays all the results.